# Best way to change messages from alert to labels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used to display my validation as well as success/failure messages through alert pop-ups but now my requirement is to display the same using HTML label texts and make them disappear after a particular amount of time. I am currently using a timeout function:

```
if ($("#lblErrorMessage").text() != "") {
    clrMsg = setTimeout(function(e) {
        $("#lblErrorMessage").text("");
        clearTimeout(clrMsg);
    }, 5000);
}
```

This approach is very messy and there is no way to check whether the message is success (needs to be displayed for longer) or error/failure message (needs to be displayed for shorter period). Can anyone suggest a function which can be used throughout the page and also meet the requirements I want?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an added class?

You don't show how you add the message in `#lblErrorMessage`...
But I suppose you can also add a class to it like "success" or "fail".

```
$("#lblErrorMessage").text("Some success messsage to user.").addClass("success");
removeMessage();
```

or

```
$("#lblErrorMessage").text("Some error messsage to user.").addClass("fail");
removeMessage();
```

Then, here is the new setTimeout function:

```
function removeMessage(){
    if ($("#lblErrorMessage").text() != "") {
        if $("#lblErrorMessage").hasClass("success"){
            clrDelay = 5000;
        }
        else if $("#lblErrorMessage").hasClass("fail"){
            clrDelay = 2500;
        } 
        clrMsg = setTimeout(function(e) {
            $("#lblErrorMessage").text("");
            //clearTimeout(clrMsg);     // No use for that.
            $("#lblErrorMessage").removeClass("success fail");    // Remove classes for future messages.
        }, clrDelay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this